# append an array to ul block - wrong?! jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have some problem with append array to a html: 
I create an array with html, first element is "li", than "img" and last element is "/li"

it returns

```
<li></li>
<img src="...">
```

but i need:

```
<li>
  <img src="...">
</li>
```

here is [jsfeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/akdes/pzrLm2bb/)

here js:

```
var items = [];
items.push( "<li class='cd-item'>" );
items.push( "bar" );
items.push("</li>");
var itm = items.join(''); 
$(".cd-items").append(itm);
```

what do i wrong?

Thanks!

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please include your jQuery in your question; the demo is a nice bonus, but without the relevant, problematic, code in the question your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `join()`

```js
var items = [];
items.push( "<li class='cd-item'>" );
items.push( "<img src='images/source.jpg'>" );
items.push("</li>");
 var html = items.join('');
$(".cd-items").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-items">
    foo
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change this line:

```
$(".cd-items").append(items);
```

to

```
$(".cd-items").html(items);
```

see [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) reference for more details.